# Defining Redis Database at Runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis, redis-py

I am using the Redis client for Python called Redis-py. The GitHub library is located here https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py. I was wondering if there was any way to set the Redis database initialization values at runtime. For example, if I have a global variable called `db` and I want to change the value of `db` based on the configuration (dev, test, prod, etc), is there any way I can do this. Redispy only provides a constructor, but doesn't provide any way to initialize at runtime.

One way to do this is define the global variable `db` to be None and use a function to set change the `db` variable to the correct redis db. But, I am really trying to avoid using the `global` keyword/changing a global variable in a function. What are some other ways of doing this?

Comment: Please do not vandalise your post. This may result in a [question ban](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans). By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Comment: Do not delete your question when you get your answer. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378440/caveat-emptor-making-students-aware-they-cannot-delete-their-homework-questions.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you're talking about dynamically changing the *client* configuration or the *server* configuration.

If you want to change the client configuration, you would just create a new connection by instantiating a new instance of the `Redis` object. You can see an example of that in the [documentation](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py#getting-started):

```
>>> r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
```

If you want to "change" the `db` you'd merely create a new connection (i.e. `Redis` object) with the new `db` value.

If you're talking about dynamically changing the configuration of the Redis server, you can do that with the [`CONFIG SET`](https://redis.io/commands/config-set) command.

Comment: Related. Can I change the client side configuration dynamically? Say I have to connect to one redis, but I get a timeout, so I should be able to connect to another redis which has a different connection string. How do I go about this? Where/How do I change the code at the application level to get this done?

Comment: @scientific_explorer: I don't know, I doubt that capability is a documented part of the redis-py API which means that you would have to dig around in the internals. You should probably ask a new question about it.